# How to pass a <div> in innerHTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have following code:

```
widgetEl.innerHTML = "<h2>" + name + "</h2><h3>Time Series</h3>" ;
```

It is working fine. I need to pass a div instead of `<h3>Time Series</h3>`. How can I pass the follwing div instead of `<h3>Time Series</h3>`.

```
<div id="test" class="hide" style="min-width: 700px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Any help please....

Comment: Replace one string of HTML, that you *don't* want, with the string of HTML that you *do* want..?

Comment: The `div#test` is an existing DOM-Element?

Comment: This question isn't clear. Is the `<div...` a string or a DOM Element? If an element, do you want to move it, or copy it? You should explain clearly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've a quoting problem. Use single quotes around the JS:

```
widgetEl.innerHTML = '<h2>' + name + '</h2><div id="test" class="hide" style="min-width: 700px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>';
```

Or if the `div` is a real HTML element:

```
widgetEl.innerHTML = '<h2>' + name + '</h2>' + document.getElementById('test').outerHTML.replace(/id\="test"/, 'id="test2"');
```

Notice, that in the latter case you have to change the id of the `div` to avoid double `id`s.

Comment: @ Teemu you appended both `h3` and `div`

Comment: Are you sure the DIV in question is a string? Doesn't it seem just a little too obvious if it is?

Comment: I guess it's possible that the original string exists, and he wants to modify the string by removing the `h3` part and concatenating the `div` string. No matter what, I have a feeling that he's taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Could just appendChild the div instead of getting the outer html, unless hes wanting to clone it, even then could just use cloneNode and appendChild, or replaceChild

Comment: If the intent is to clone an existing `div`, then you're going to end up with duplicate IDs. I agree with @PatrickEvans that if that's the case, then it should be `.cloneNode()`'d and `.appendChild()`'d but also change its ID.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is unclear of what you are wanting to do, here are several attempts at what you are doing using different techniques for different situations

To concatenate the dom string, use single quotes when needing to use double in the string

```
widgetEl.innerHTML = "<h2>" + name + "</h2>"+'<div id="test" class="hide" style="min-width: 700px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>';
```

To replace the h3 with a existing div element, using `replaceChild`

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var h3 = widgetEl.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
widgetEl.replaceChild(test,h3);
```

Another way, use `remove()` to remove old element, and then `appendChild` to append the div
Of course using this way may not lead to what you want as there could be other stuff around the h3, just assuming the string in your example is what is currently in the div.

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
widgetEl.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].remove();
widgetEl.appendChild(test);
```

If needing to clone

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
widgetEl.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].remove();
widgetEl.appendChild(test.cloneNode());
```

Also remember to change the ID as all id's need to be unique

```
var clone = document.getElementById("test").cloneNode();
clone.id = "someOtherUniqueID";
var h3 = widgetEl.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
widgetEl.replaceChild(clone,h3);
```

Also note the use of getElementsByTagName will try to get any element with tag name `h3`, I am assuming here that it is the only one in that element, you will have to add other measures to make sure you are getting the right one if there are other h3 elements.

Comment: What if the `div` is empty, or it has totally different content?

Comment: Well I mentioned that i was assuming that the string he shows, is what was in the one element, and say in last paragraph mention that he will need to use appropriate measures to make sure he has the right one.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("content-11").innerHTML = '<div v-bind:style="stylesFontSize">' 
  + '<p v-bind:style="stylesMessage" class="c-ecard__message" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 69.7%; max-width: 57.7%; height: 68.3%; left: 42.1%; top: 0.8%; line-height: 1;" v-html="this.$options.filters.newline(preparedMessage)"></p></div>';
```